# Python subprocess command arguments

Tags: python, linux, arguments, subprocess

Why if I run `subprocess.check_output('ls')` everything is working but when I add argument to command like: `subprocess.check_output('ls -la')` I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I pass command arguments into `subprocess.check_output()`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to split the arguments into a list:

```
subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la'])
```

The `subprocess` callables do not parse the command out to individual arguments like the shell does. You either need to do this yourself or you need to tell `subprocess` to use the shell explicitly:

```
subprocess.check_output('ls -la', shell=True)
```

The latter is not recommended as it can expose your application to security vulnerabilities. You can use `shlex.split()` to parse a shell-like command line if needed:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('ls -la')
['ls', '-la']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find [sh.py](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/) more friendly:

```
import sh

print sh.ls("-la")
```